# Asynchronous async await method to generate pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, asynchronous

I decided to convert the method that generates a PDF to asynchronous call. The asynchronous call doesn't produce the requested PDF and I have no idea why this is happening

The client who calls the async operation is as follows:

```
public QuotationResponse CreateQuotation(IQuotation quotation)
{
    ...
    // Create Quotation PDF
    _pdfWriter.GeneratePdfAsync(response);
    return response;
}
```

The class responsible for generating the PDF is the following:

```
public class Writer
{
   //... other class methods
   public async Task GeneratePdfAsync(QuotationResponse response)
   {
       await new Task(() =>
       {
            var currentPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
            var formFile = Path.Combine(currentPath, Settings.Default.QUOTATION_TEMPLATE_PATH);
            var newFile = Path.Combine(currentPath, Settings.Default.QUOTATION_PDF_PATH);
            var reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                ....
                // flatten form fields and close document
                stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                stamper.Close();
            }
       });
   }
}
```

I suspect that I'm not doing something right with the *async - await* operation but don't know what. Could you please assist?

Comment: Your PDF generation code does not seem to be asynchronous. You gain no value by creating a new task. Having said this, your direct problem is that you should use `Task.Run(..` instead of `new Task(...`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain not really it should be void. The entire pdf generation takes place within the GeneratePdfAsync method

Comment: I did not notice at first that GeneratePdfAsync was defined in the 2nd code example, To add on what Yacoub said, you should never need to do `new Task(...` also, you never await the task returned from GeneratePdfAsync.

Comment: what is the `response` you return on your `CreateQuotation` method?

Comment: @Luiso its a QuotationResponse instance, which is passed to the async operation to generate the PDF. The async operation is a user of the response and doesn't alter its properties

Comment: I think your issue is that you are not `await`ing your `GeneratePdfAsync` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use the `Task` constructor. Ever. It has absolutely no valid use cases. At all. For any kind of approach to any kind of problem. [Full details on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Since there is no asynchronous work to do, you should just use synchronous methods:

```
public class Writer
{
  //... other class methods
  public void GeneratePdfAsync(QuotationResponse response)
  {
    var currentPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
    ...
  }
}
```

If you want to call this from a GUI application and don't want to block the UI thread, then you can *call* it on a background thread by using `await Task.Run`, as such:

```
QuotationResponse response = await Task.Run(() => CreateQuotation(quotation));
```